# TypeScript, why? "is not assignable to type"

Tags: typescript

I have two variables with same type, copy is taken with spread operator, but TypeScript check does not accept it why?

```js
const [startPaymentIn, setStartPaymentIn] = useState<
  StartPaymentIn | undefined
>(undefined);

let startPaymentIn2: StartPaymentIn | undefined = {
  ...startPaymentIn,
};

setStartPaymentIn(startPaymentIn2);
```

Error:

```
ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx
./tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx 172:20-35
[tsl] ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx(172,21)
      TS2322: Type '{ eventId?: string | undefined; quantity?: number | undefined; link?: string | undefined; partnerData?: NameAndAddress | undefined; passTypeId?: string | undefined; ... 17 more ...; deliveryData?: NameAndAddress | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'StartPaymentIn'.
  Types of property 'eventId' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

```js
export type StartPaymentIn = {
  eventId: string;
  quantity?: number;
  link?: string;
  partnerData?: NameAndAddress;
  passTypeId?: string;
  eventTimesSelected?: EventTimesSelected;
...
```

Comment: The error message is straightforward: `eventId` is typed as `string`, but because the "parent" object `startPaymentIn2` can be undefined, so can its members (which would be implicitly accessed via the spread operator), so all its members are also implicitly also-possibly-`undefined`, hence the right-hand-side type is `string | undefined` instead of just `string`. You need to assert that `startPaymentIn2` cannot be `undefined`.

Comment: yes, but if remove `undefined` from `startPaymentIn2`, then the othe rway around will fail, in the same reason.

Comment: You also have `| undefined` as the type-args for `useState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `startPaymentIn` is `undefined` the result of `{ ...startPaymentIn }` will be `{}` which is not compatible with `StartPaymentIn | undefined`.

What you can do is `startPaymentIn && { ...startPaymentIn }`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGAnYAFeIC2EB2wCS2UAvFAN4BQUUEAbjvgCYBcUAzsIgJbYDmA3JSgBHAK7xcnUAH4W2ERgBGERAKoAbbgGsZbDt37kAvuXIMIAYzVJo5gPbZ2UAB4s4SVOiy4CUAD5QRbDMAM24IBhM7B2AoEFcEZDRMeh9-QJCwhmJnKAAyXLIAOmKnQyA)